# in the table, the colour of rows should be green if response contains status having "Claimed", and if status is "unclaimed color is red."

Tags: angular, typescript

this is my code i want to add the code which will solve the problem to add color to the rows of the table.
if the status in response is claimed the color should be green and if the status in response in unclaimed the color of row must be red.

````
HTMl code: 
<mtx-grid [data]="ticketResults"
                [columns]="columns"
                [rowStriped]="true"
                [pageOnFront]="true"
                [showPaginator]="true"
                [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,33.33,100]"
                [pageIndex]="0"
                [pageSize]="10"
                >
      </mtx-grid>```

Typescript code: 

columns: MtxGridColumn[] = [
    { header: 'Sr No', field: 'sr', width:'70px',},
    { header: 'Userid', field: 'userid'},
     //multiple columns..
    { header: 'Draw Date', field: 'drawtime', type:'date', typeParameter:{format:'dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a'}},
    { header: 'Status', field: 'status',},
  ];

function :

getdata(){
    this.dataSrv.get('XXX').subscribe((response:any)=>{
        this.Results = response;
    })
  }

response: 
{
points: XX
status: "Unclaimed"
ticketno: "XXXXXXXXX"
userid: "XXX"
name: "XXXXXXX"
email: "XXXX"
}

the response is collected by the function getdata(). so in that response the status field is present which contains either "claimed" or "unclaimed".
I want to add css to rows as the ifthe row conatains status is claimed then color of row should be green, and if the status is unclaimed the color of rowshould be red.
````